# Receiving an error while excluding NULLs from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query like this:

```
SELECT distinct [F_Exhibitor_Name],
       F_Site 
  FROM [V_ExhibitorLocation] 
 WHERE F_ExhibitionCode ='10996' is not null 
 ORDER BY F_Exhibitor_Name
```

but its showing error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'

.

Comment: That's because you are telling it to look for a value that is not null, don't do that. Remove the `is not null` portion.

Comment: while executing this query in result set i am getting sum null rows

Comment: Rows are not null, values are null. You would need to check for a specific column being null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following boolean condition is simply not valid any way that you parse it:

```
 WHERE F_ExhibitionCode ='10996' is not null
```

Presumably, you just want:

```
 WHERE F_ExhibitionCode = '10996'
```

This is equivalent to:

```
 WHERE F_ExhibitionCode = '10996' AND F_ExhibitionCode IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove `is not null` as below

```
SELECT distinct [F_Exhibitor_Name],F_Site 
FROM [V_ExhibitorLocation] 
Where F_ExhibitionCode ='10996' 
order by F_Exhibitor_Name
```

or add condition using filed that can't be null as  below

```
SELECT distinct [F_Exhibitor_Name],F_Site 
FROM [V_ExhibitorLocation] 
Where F_ExhibitionCode ='10996' 
and  [column]   is not null 
order by F_Exhibitor_Name
```

Comment: but stil getting null values

Comment: @jasemhi Where do you have null values ?